# Name of a groupoid

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, groupoids

Let $S$ be an arbitrary set. Consider the category

- whose objects are the points of $S$;
- whose morphisms are the pairs $(a,b) \in S^2$, with starting and ending objects respectively $a$ and $b$;
- such that, for all $(a,b),(b,c) \in S^2$, $(a,b) \circ (b,c):=(a,c)$.

It is clear that this category is a groupoid.

> **Question:** Does this groupoid have a name in the literature?

Comment: I have definitely heard it called "chaotic / indiscrete groupoid", but I can't find the reference for now

Comment: This is equivalent to say for each pair of objects $a,b$, there is a unique morphism between them. I have never heard about it before, but a quick search led to [this](https://www.matem.unam.mx/~omar/groupoids/day1.html) : "An indiscrete groupoid is one where there is a unique morphism between any pair of objects", and [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codiscrete%20groupoid): Chaotic, codiscrete, indiscrete, coarse, pair ... apparently it has a lot of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the [indiscrete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indiscrete+category) or [codiscrete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codiscrete+groupoid) groupoid, by analogy with the indiscrete topology.